# What is the difference between [ngFor] and [ngForOf] in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

As per my understanding, *Both are doing the same* functions. But,

- `ngFor` would be works like as [collections](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_collections.htm)?.
- `ngForOf` would be works like as [generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)?.

---

> **Is my understanding is correct? or
>      Could you please share more difference's(details) about `ngFor` and `ngForOf`?**

Comment: Good question! i also wanted to ask! btw, your links for both collections and generics are same

Comment: @Sajeetharan Typo issue. Sorry for that. Now I have updated my question. thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/86b2b2504f336e9ae69dfbc46c6731468781b944

Comment: @yurzui, good catch. So it seems as though the class was previously NgFor and it got changed in the move to angular v4, and the key thing is that we as a community were none the wiser. Awesome backwards compatibility

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`ngFor`  and `ngForOf` are not two distinct things - they are actually the selectors of the NgForOf directive.

If you examine the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts), you'll see that the NgForOf directive has as its selector: `[ngFor][ngForOf]` , meaning that both attributes need to be present on an element for the directive to 'activate' so to speak.

When you use `*ngFor`, the Angular compiler de-sugars that syntax into its cannonical form which has both attributes on the element.

So,

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items"></div>
```

desugars to:

```
 <template [ngFor]="let item of items">
     <div></div>
 </template>
```

This first de-sugaring is due to the '*'. The next de-sugaring is because of the micro syntax: "let item of items". The Angular compiler de-sugars that to:

```
 <template ngFor let-item="$implicit" [ngForOf]="items">
   <div>...</div>
 </template>
```

*(where you can think of $implicit as an internal variable that the directive uses to refer to the current item in the iteration).*

In its canonical form, the ngFor attribute is just a marker, while the ngForOf attribute is actually an input to the directive that points to the the list of things you want to iterate over.

You can check out the [Angular microsyntax guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#microsyntax) to learn more.

Comment: Isn't `ngFor` the actual directive whereas `ngForOf` is "just" a property of the "de-sugared" version?

Comment: well, technically, ngForOf is the name of the class that implements the  directive (again, see the source).  It's just that no one actually refers to it by that name - ngFor is basically how its referred to in all documentation and conversations.

Comment: Your desugaring examples are both quite wrong. I don't think there are 2 steps, and the end result would be `<template ngFor let-item="$implicit" [ngForOf]="items"> </template>`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you are right - i put the directives in the wrong place - i updated the code examples. And you're probably also right that the de-sugaring happens in just one step, but i think in this case, it's useful to separate the desugaring of the structural directive from the desugaring of the let micro-syntax to show that they are (relatively) independent things

Answer (score 6):

`ngFor` is a structural directive of Angular which replaces the `ng-repeat` attribute of AngularJS

You can use `ngFor` as a shorthand

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</li>
```

or as the longhand version

```
<template ngFor let-item="$implicit" [ngForOf]="items">
  {{item.name}}
</template>
```

Comment: `shorthand` and `longhand` means no of data size? or what?

Comment: It means: Difference of usage for the same purpose and effect

Comment: Okay now I understand it. But whenever am seeing this line in the document `ngForOf: NgIterable<T>: The value of the iterable expression. Useful when the expression is more complex then a property access, for example when using the async pipe (userStreams | async).` really not understandable.

Comment: Let's say your `items` collection is not a simple collection but rather a collection which is not yet available and will only be available after some asynchronous call. So you won't have `items` yet but only an Observable or Promise (let's call it futureItems). In that case you'd like to use the async pipe `let item of (futureItems|async)` which is not possible. But you can use the longhand version with `[ngForOf]="futureItems | async"`

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion what I got from the angular document,

- `[ngFor]` is ***not*** **`type safe`**
- `[NgForOf]` is **`type safe`**

Because both class details are little different

- `ngFor` Class type is `any` type
- But `ngForOf` class type is generic 
  `ngForOf : NgIterable<T>`

---

`ngForOf` looks like generics which I have already mentioned in my question.

Comment: Interesting. However, since they are used from within templates, this matters less in practice than it otherwise would. That said, the number of Angular APIs, including ones not intended for template use such as `FormBuilder`, which are not type checked is troubling.

Answer (score 4):

NgFor can iterate an array but in ngContainer, ngContent we cannot iterate ngFor directly so For iterating we 
can use [ngForOf] . Here i is variable, ratings is an array.

Ex.

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-i [ngForOf]="ratings">
                  <option *ngIf="i<=22" [ngValue]="i">{{i}}:00 Hrs.</option>
   </ng-template>
```

At this example, I want to apply a ngFor and ngIf simultaneously, so i used it.

The other view is that at a normal  if we apply ngFor then at rendering it converts it into

```
<template ngFor let-i [ngForOf]="ratings">
   <HTML Element>...</HTML Element>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit version

- `(<template ngFor ...>)` allows to apply the directive to multiple elements at once

Implicit version

- only wraps the element where it is applied