# What is Angular [ngForOf] usage

Tags: angular

One of a project where I'm handling is having below code.Can you tell me what it does? I know about `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`.But what are these `[ngForOf]="topicdata"` and  `ngFor let-topic`? Can I simplify below code in a better way?

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-topic [ngForOf]="topicdata">
        <topic *ngIf="topic.num_of_definitions>0" [data]="topic"></topic>
 </ng-template>
```

I would like to have it as shown below.

```
<topic *ngFor="let topic of topicdata" [data]="topic" 
*ngIf="topic.num_of_definitions>0"></topic>
```

But then it shows this error:

> [Angular] Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use
>   only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \[ngFor\] and \[ngForOf\] in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388893/what-is-the-difference-between-ngfor-and-ngforof-in-angular2)

Comment: also see here https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Also see the [Angular documentation page on structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor) - all of them compile down to `ng-template` in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*ngFor` directive is something Angular calls [**microsyntax**](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax). *Microsyntax* essentially gives developers a way of configuring a directive in a more compact and simple way. You can see that something is using the microsyntax for the preceding `*`.

The code:

```
<topic *ngFor="let topic of topicdata"> </topic>
```

Will for example be equal to:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-topic [ngForOf]="topicdata">
   <topic> ... </topic>
</ng-template>
```

Like in the example you have in your question.

So in short - you can replace you code with `*ngFor="let topic of topicdata"` and get the same result.

**EDIT - TO FIX: *ngIf on the same line**

Angular doesn't allow you to use two or more *structural directives* on the same element. So as a way of using `*ngIf`on the same line I recommend looping out an `<ng-container>` element and put your `<topic>` inside that one.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let topic of topicdata">
   <topic *ngIf="topic.num_of_definitions > 0"> ... </topic>
<ng-container>
```

More in on `ng-container` [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer)

Comment: This is working `<topic *ngFor="let topic of topicdata" [data]="topic"></topic>`.But thi is not.Why? `<ng-template *ngFor="let topic of topicdata"> <topic [data]="topic"></topic> </ng-template>`

Comment: That's because the `*ngFor` will create the `ng-template` for you behind the scenes - so putting a `*ngFor` on an `ng-template` wouldn't make sense. Go for `<topic *ngFor="let topic of topicdata" [data]="topic"></topic>` :)

Comment: I can't do that hence `*ngIf="topic.num_of_definitions>0"`also there.please see update above.So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a different syntax of ngFor. `let-topic [ngForOf]="topicdata"` creates a topic variables from topicdata array. You can just write it as follows which creates the syntax you used (with ng-template)

```
<div *ngFor="let topic of topicdata">
    // some template
</div>
```

You can find more here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor

Comment: Yes, I would like this syntax.I'll try this and come back.Thanks.

Comment: This is working `<topic *ngFor="let topic of topicdata" [data]="topic"></topic>`.But thi is not.Why?  `<ng-template *ngFor="let topic of topicdata">
       <topic [data]="topic"></topic>
      </ng-template>`

Comment: Yes it is actually my bad. You can't use this syntax with ng-template. Because *ngFor actually sugared version of `ng-template ngForOf`. You can find more here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor