# Angular4 ngIf local variable assignment and comparison at the same time?

Tags: angular

I'm using the [new Angular local variable assignment feature](https://alligator.io/angular/ngif-new-features-angular4/) to reference the result of an async pipe in child elements under an `ngIf`:

```
<nav *ngIf="dataService.count$ | async as count">
  <div *ngIf="count > 1">
    There's more than one!  It's actually {{count}}.
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I have an extra `div` in the hierarchy just to grab the result of the async pipe and then do a comparison against it.  I feel like I should be able to do this in a single expression but I can't find enough documentation about the new feature.  I've tried a variety of approaches with parens, using `| async; let count` instead, etc, but I can't figure out how to do both things in one line.

(A pointer to any documentation on local variable declaration syntax in `ngIf` would be much appreciated too -- I had never heard of `foo$ | async as foo` until I saw it here on SO.)

Comment: You could use `ng-container`, this still gives you an extra 'container' in the code, but not when rendering the view.

Comment: This question should have angular 4 tag.

Comment: My answer here is not really the answer to your question, but very related, and the same things can be applied: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696109/2521893

Comment: It's in Angular doc: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf and the same kind of question asked here: github.com/angular/angular/issues/16173

Comment: Thanks Vega, I did read those docs and while they mention `async as` they don't say anything about `foo$ | async; let foo` which I believe also works.  Based on your GH issue link, it looks like this doesn't have a shorthand yet, and I might be stuck with 2 elements.

Comment: Turns out I should have been using `ng-template` instead of a `div` but otherwise the solution in the OP is what I'm still using.  There are a few issues open with quality of life improvements like this (or e.g. having an "empty" construct for `*ngFor`) but I haven't seen any movement on them in a long time.

Comment: Per @Jan_V my last comment above is wrong. `ng-template` does not normally render but `ng-container` does.

Comment: It's not bad to have extra divs or spans or containers. I know it's not the prettiest solution but sometimes I have to nest things another layer for these kinds of operations

Comment: Changing the structure of your DOM to suit the foibles of the templating language is a hassle, though. For example, your CSS -- or worse, the CSS of a library you're relying on, like Angular Material -- may use direct-descendent selectors that break if you insert an unnecessary `div` or `span` just to make Ivy happy.  It's just a good practice to avoid the excess structure if possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's still not an easy solution to my original question but I have found a related pattern that might help others in a similar situation:

```html
<div id="top-container" *ngIf="{
  count: dataService.count$ | async,
  otherVal: dataService.val$ | async
}; let props">
  <nav *ngIf="props.count > 1">
    There's more than one!  It's actually {{props.count}}.
  </nav>
  <span *ngIf="props.otherVal?.startsWith('abc')">...</span>
</div>
```

Basically you can define an inline plain object whose values are async-pipe subscriptions inside the `*ngIf` structural directive of a top level element.  The object will always be defined (after ViewInit, which is important because it breaks `@ViewChild(..., {static: true}`!) so the if-condition never fails and the top level DOM element always exists.  But thanks to the way the async-pipe works, any change to the Observables that back any property will trigger change detection in your component, and you only get one subscription to each.

If you don't have a top level component to stick your bag-of-async-pipes into, or the existence of a top level `*ngIf` overcomplicates your use of `ViewChild`, you can use nested `ng-container` as @Jan_V suggested in the comments, which avoids unused elements in the resulting DOM structure.  (I'll leave the question open in case there's a better answer out there.)