# Do I use NgFor or NgForOf?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the [angular API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) documentation it says to use `NgForOf` instead of `NgFor` with version 4.0 onwards. But the [Fundamentals](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor), and [Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#list-heroes-with-ngfor), documentation demonstrate`NgFor`, and make no mention of `NgForOf`.

Is there anyone who can clarify  this for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `*ngFor` is the sugar-coated version of `ngForOf` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388893/what-is-the-difference-between-ngfor-and-ngforof-in-angular2) and as you've said it appears that `*ngFor` is now deprecated so it is better to use `ngForOf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They just renamed the class. `NgForOf` is the new class, `NgFor` is now only an alias and will go away eventually.
  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/09d9f5fe54e7108c47de61393e10712f8239d824/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L205

This only affects you if you are using a reference to the `NgFor` class in your code. The directive is imported using the `CommonModule`.
The selector is unchanged, therefore if you are only using `ngFor` in your template, nothing will change.

Answer (score 4):

ngForOf is the name of the class that implements the *ngFor directive. Its was the class type that changed (from ngFor to ngForOf) not the directive itself. So in our templates we still use *ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

The difference I see

[NgForOf] is used to assign a source value into a target within any tag. ngForOf is a prop of NgFor class. In ngForOf we assign our array to iterate. **ngForOf : NgIterable**

[ngFor] doesn't require a type. Using this will mean the prop NgForOf is ngForOf : any