# For loop on angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular. I wanted to know the difference between `NgFor` and `NgForOf`. The site says `NgFor` is deprecated and suggest to use `NgForOf`, can I continue using the former or should I change them to later. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Please note that I have also asked about using it against deprecation or not. Also my question is regarding `angular4`not `angular2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[snorkpete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11742/snorkpete) wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43389260/20057):

> `ngFor` and `ngForOf` are not two distinct things - they are actually
>   the selectors of the `NgForOf` directive.

Also there for `ngFor` Class detail is any type, i.e `ngForOf : any` whereas `ngForOf` has a class definiton as follows `ngForOf : NgIterable<T>`

Comment: Thanks that helps. Please explain, should I use it or not ?

Comment: Found a similar discussion here:[Is it wrong to use Deprecated methods or classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941912/8313343). You may read this and get an idea.