# Difference between ngFor and ngForOf in angular8 or higher?

Tags: angular

In which case we have to use the NgFor or others

Angular 2 - ngFor vs. ngForOf

1. ```
   The [ngFor] is not a type safe
   ```
2. ```
   The [NgForOf] is a type Safe
   ```
3. ```
   The [NgFor] directive instantiates a template once per item from iterate
   ```
4. ```
   The [ngFor] and [ngForOf] are actually the selectors of the [NgForOf] directive and it is not two distinct things
   ```
5. ```
   The [ngFor] will be works like as collections
   ```
6. ```
   The [ngForOf] will be works like as generics
   ```

Comment: You can answer this question by yourself by comparing the documentation pages of [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) and [`ngForOf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \[ngFor\] and \[ngForOf\] in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388893/what-is-the-difference-between-ngfor-and-ngforof-in-angular2)